# How to refresh a jlabel?

Tags: jbutton, jlabel, repaint

so Im using a jlabel to say the question currently running in a form, but when I click on the JButton send I want the jlabel to show the next question. I tried making a new instance in the jlabel with the next question (lblPregunta = new JLabel(datos.get(indice).getPregunta()); ) and also using lblPregunta.repaint();
but the question in the jlabel doesnt change when I click on the JButton send (I tested and I know that the question running goes to the next one, the form works, but the jlabel doesnt change)

Sorry for my vague english

Answer (score 0):

Why you better not use a JTextField and disable writing to it, and you just do something like this :

```
ask_field.setEditable(false);//this only disable the user capacity to write on it
ask_field.setText(datos.get(indice).getPregunta());
```